# Having trouble writing unit test for Kotlin Object

Tags: unit-testing, object, kotlin, tdd

With the logic of TDD in mind and trying to understand how to write unit test's, I am having trouble with Kotlin object.  The test pass but I am unsure if this is actually the right test.  I am trying to make sure that the Logger.i() method is called and that it saves into the database.  But at the moment I am stuck at just its called part.

My Object

```
object Logger {
    fun i(tag: String, msg: String, tr: Throwable? = null): Int  {
        insertIntoLogDatabase(createLogModel("i", tag, msg, tr))
        return if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(tag, msg, tr) else 0
    }

    private fun insertIntoLogDatabase(log: LogModel) {
        //Insert into Log DB
        logRepo.upsert(log)
    }

    private fun createLogModel(type: String, tag: String, msg: String, tr: Throwable?) = LogModel(0, type, tag, msg, if (tr != null) tr.message + "\n" + tr?.stackTrace.contentToString() else null)

    fun setLogRepo(logRepo: LogRepository) {
        this.logRepo = logRepo
    }
}
```

with this, I know that I have to call Logger.setLogRepo(logRemp) to give the Logger access to the repo (and this works)

Where I am stuck is I am trying to unit test the Log.i method call

I have this

```
@Mock
lateinit var log: Logger

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    Logger.setLogRepository(logRepo)
}

@Test
fun `log i failed`() {

    // When
    log.i("Test", "Test1")

    // Then
    verify(log, times(1)).i("Test", "Test1")
}
```

I mean this works but is it correct (my gut tells me that something is wrong that I am not actually testing the Logger.i() method

please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have to test that when you log the data, it should get stored in the repo in the format you want, and you want to test basically that when you have given the work of sending log to the Logger, it is getting sent to the repository in the correct format and you will assert against that.

So you're test case will look like,

```
@Mock
lateinit var logRepo: LogRepository

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    Logger.setLogRepository(logRepo)
}

@Test
fun `when an item is logged, it gets stored in the repository`()
{
  val expectedData= <valueThatShouldBeSentToRepo>

  Logger.i("Test", "Test1")

  verify(logRepo).upsert(expectedData)

}
```

Comment: I have tried that and I get the following error

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
logRepo.upsert(
    0: [Test] Test1 @ 2019-03-15T15:04:29.024

);
-> at com.mycomp.mytest.utilities.log.LogTest.logger i failed(LogTest.kt:66)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
logRepo.upsert(
    0: [Test] Test1 @ 2019-03-15T15:04:31.206

);

Comment: Basically, because expected data and Logger.i are 2 separate things. so they dont match?

Comment: Paste your LogModel class, and if it's not a data class then make it a data class

Comment: Its definitely a data class :)
`@Entity(tableName = "Logs")
data class LogModel (
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var logID: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type") var type: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tag") var tag: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "msg") var msg: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tr") var tr: String?
) {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_date")
    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
    var createDate: LocalDateTime? = LocalDateTime.now()
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$logID: [$tag] $msg @ $createDate\n"
    }
}`

Comment: As the createDate variable is set to the initialisation time, it will be different of the expected value and the actual value as the expected value is created first, and actual value is created after that , inside logger. This can be resolved by 2 things, i) Exclude createDate from equals method by moving createDate variable from constructor to inside the class so two objects with same data but with different creation time will be true.

Comment: ii) use a class to provide date to the Logger and then set the createDate manually during LogModel object creation by calling getCurrentTime() from that and during test pass a constant value which will make the time of the expectedData and the actual data same.

Comment: createdDate is actually already inside the class and not in the constructor (I know its hard to see in the comments above.) But I am not sure how to exclude it from the Equals method (This is something I might need to look into)

Comment: I call this Log.i("Test", "Test1") verify(logRepo).upsert(testLog1)? The class is Logger right? Can you please add the updated test in the question?

Comment: I removed createdDate completely and I still get the same error I call this Logger.i("Test", "Test1") verify(logRepo).upsert(testLog1) Argument(s) are different! Wanted: logRepo.upsert( LogModel(logID=0, type=i, tag=Test, msg=Test1, tr=) ); -> at com.mycomp.myproj.utilities.logger.LogTest.aaa(LogTest.kt:41) Actual invocation has different arguments: logRepo.upsert( LogModel(logID=0, type=i, tag=Test, msg=Test1, tr=) ); -> at com.mycomp.myproj.utilities.log.Logger.insertIntoLogDatabase(Log.kt:60) I also took out the toString function

Comment: Can you take the picture of difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190220/discussion-between-harshith-shetty-and-crash1hd).